# Interpretation of centered seasonal dummy variables

Tags: r, vector-autoregression, seasonality

When estimating a VAR model in R with the VAR()-function from the package 'vars' (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/vars/versions/1.5-3/topics/VAR) it allows for inclusion of centered seasonal dummy variables (integer value of frequency).

In my example I estimate a VAR with the log of sales and spend on different media, innovation++ as endogenous variables with 1 lag. I want to include quarterly dummies, and estimate with 'season = 4'. Which quarter is then included in the intercept (aka the base category)? And how are the estimates of a 'centered seasonal dummy' interpreted? I struggle to find material that easily explains how the 'centered seasonal dummies' work and are interpreted.

These are the estimation results from one of the endogenous variables, log(sales):

```
$logsales

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ -1 + ., data = datamat)

Coefficients:
          log(sales).l1             logsumOLV.l1         logsumPressAd.l1            logsumSoME.l1  
              5.806e-01               -4.741e-04                3.182e-04               -7.711e-05  
      logsumTVCinema.l1        logsumOutdoors.l1         logInnovation.l1             logprice1.l1  
              2.012e-03                1.277e-03                9.529e-04                7.420e-01  
       logassortment.l1                    const                      sd1                      sd2  
              1.687e-01               -4.016e+00                7.541e-02                7.225e-02  
                    sd3                     exo1  
              8.118e-02                1.316e+00
```